# Order detail page says "Customer not notified" for orders placed using PayPal

Tags: email, order-status, order-email, order-confirmation

If a customer pays by creditcard (Authorize.net) a comment in the order detail page says

> Customer Notified

If a customer pays via PayPal the comment on order detail page says

> Customer Not Notified

First I thought there is an issue with the order confirmation email (that it does not get send for PayPal orders) but the 'email_sent' attribute in the sales_flat_order table will be set for both (value = 1), no matter if CC or PayPal was used. So the email did get send.

I can confirm that this happens in Mage_Sales_Model_Order::sendNewOrderEmail(). But where does the comment will be added? I would like to have Magento add the same comment for PayPal. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I am looking at the same problem on our 1.9 Magento shop today, did you ever find any solutions?